# Not Able to Run TeamViews on Ubuntu Server 18.04 With Putty

Tags: shell, ubuntu, permissions, teamviewer

I am trying to run TeamViewer on Ubuntu Server 18.04 through Putty connection but I am getting following errors. I have already sudo installed Ubuntu Desktop on this server and I am hoping to create a remote connect to the GUI but I am stuck here

```
a@gisdev05:~$ teamviewer
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/home/a/.local/share/teamviewer13’: Permission denied
Error: Could not create /home/a/.local/share/teamviewer13/logfiles
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/home/a/.local/share/teamviewer13’: Permission denied
Error: Could not create /home/a/.local/share/teamviewer13/logfiles
Error: InitDirs failed. (2)

a@gisdev05:~$ ^C
```

[image]

I was however able to run the `TeamViewer` before running

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

Can you please let me know how to fix this?

Comment: Did you at some point run `teamviewer` with `sudo`? if so you will likely need to re-take ownership of the `./local/share/teamviewer13` directory

Comment: I tried running `teamviewr` both with and without `sudo`. Can you please let me know how to `re-take ownership of the ./local/share/teamviewer13 directory`

Answer (score 1):

You inadvertently changed the owner/group on the directory `/home/a/.local/share/teamviewer13`. You need to fix this as root. You can do this using `sudo`:

```
$ sudo chown -R a.a /home/a/.local
```

*-or-* to use the user's default group:

```
$ sudo chown -R a: /home/a/.local
```

With this you should see this directory listed so that the owner is the user a and the group is also a.

**NOTE:** Your user a's group may not be a, it might be something else, you can confirm like this:

```
$ id -a
uid=1000(vagrant) gid=1000(vagrant) groups=1000(vagrant)
```

Here my user is vagrant, and the group is vagrant. You can confirm your directory ownership like this:

```
$ cd $HO<E/.config

$ pwd
/home/vagrant/.config

$ ls -l
total 4
drwxrwxr-x 2 vagrant vagrant 4096 Jul  3 22:52 abrt
```

**NOTE:** In the above you can see vagrant 2 times. The first is the owner and the second is the group.